# Best way to redeem ticket for car?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

GT5 gave me a gift ticket "1000", for doing 100 races. When I accepted it the darn thing gave me the very same car I had just won (a Corvette).  Was I just unlucky or is there a "trick" to using the gift car ticket?

Answer (score 3):

Tickets are random.

You can maybe use a marketplace forum (like on gtplanet.net for example) to trade it with another car you don't have, or you can use non-reversable tuning on one of them (weight red, engine tune stage, regidity), then compare performances.

Comment: I thought tickets would be random too.  So the chance of getting the same car I just won should be somewhere in the 1:1000 range.  Should have bought a lottery ticket instead :-)

Comment: Tickets are random, but within a smaller range (the level, mostly).

Answer (score 2):

You could backup your save to a memory stick before opening the ticket. Then open it from the save on you HDD. If not happy with the gift, then copy the backup back to the HDD and try again.

A lot of work though.. and might be considered cheating ;D

But at least its a posibility.